# PyZMQ: Permission denied

Tags: python, permissions, pyzmq

code:

```
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def server():
    port = '5556'
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
    socket.bind('tcp://*:%s' % port)

    for i in range(10):
        socket.send('server to client')
        msg = socket.recv()
        print msg
        time.sleep(1)

def client():
    port = '5556'
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
    socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:%s' % port)

    for i in range(10):
        msg = socket.recv()
        print msg
        socket.send('msg to server')
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=server, args=()).start()
    Process(target=client, args=()).start()
```

error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\...\zmqtest.py", line 21, in client
socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:%s' % port)
File "socket.pyx", line 444, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:4076)
File "checkrc.pxd", line 21, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:6032)
ZMQError: Permission denied
```

Its able to start process 1 for the server? Why different permission?

Trying to learn ZMQ, but cant get any of their simple examples to run cause of this. Is there somewhere to open permissions for ZMQ? Can't find documentation on the matter

Comment: the server bind is likely the only problem. you can open the port in windows firewall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only `.bind` on one side (the server).  On the client you must use `.connect`, although I get "Address already in use" error instead of Permission denied.

Try changing it so the client connects and see if it works for you:

```
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def server():
    port = '5556'
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
    socket.bind('tcp://*:%s' % port)

    for i in range(10):
        socket.send('server to client')
        msg = socket.recv()
        print msg
        time.sleep(1)

def client():
    port = '5556'
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
    socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:%s' % port)

    for i in range(10):
        msg = socket.recv()
        print msg
        socket.send('msg to server')
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=server, args=()).start()
    Process(target=client, args=()).start()
```

Comment: thank you so much for having patience with me on this blatant mistake.